# Space between Grids Semantic UI

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I am learning Semantic UI Grid these days. It's pretty cool to use, but I am having some issues with the grids. Below I created two different grids, but I don't understand why there is no spacing between the two grids and I can't figure out how to add the spacing between them (without me adding some new css). Is there a class to add to the grids to have the spacing that I want?

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui container">
    <div class="ui equal width padded grid">
        <div class="ui row">
            <div class="ui black column"></div>
            <div class="ui red column"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="ui padded grid">
        <div class="ui blue row">
            <div class="ui column">Single Row</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui yellow equal width row">
            <div class="ui green column">1</div>
            <div class="ui column">2</div>
            <div class="ui red column">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui three column row">
            <div class="ui pink left floated column">LEFT</div>
            <div class="ui pink right floated column">RIGHT</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a trouble using color with 'padded' grid. I couldn't found any SUI option, but maybe nested grid is a temporary solution.

http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html#/overview

> Colored Grids can use named colors variations to add background colors, but only with padded grid that do not include negative margins.

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui container">
    <div class="ui equal width padded grid">
        <div class="ui row">
            <div class="ui black column"></div>
            <div class="ui red column"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="ui row">
            <div class="ui column">
                 <div class="ui padded grid">
                      <div class="ui blue row">
                           <div class="ui column">Single Row</div>
                      </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui equal width row">
            <div class="ui column">
                 <div class="ui padded grid">
                      <div class="ui green row">
                           <div class="ui column">1</div>
                      </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui column">
                 <div class="ui padded grid">
                      <div class="ui yellow row">
                           <div class="ui column">2</div>
                      </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui column">
                 <div class="ui padded grid">
                      <div class="ui red row">
                           <div class="ui column">3</div>
                      </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui three column row">
            <div class="ui left floated column">
                 <div class="ui padded grid">
                      <div class="ui pink row">
                           <div class="ui column">LEFT</div>
                      </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui right floated column">
                 <div class="ui padded grid">
                      <div class="ui pink row">
                           <div class="ui column">LEFT</div>
                      </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```